# Angular preload and canload

Tags: angular, guard, lazy-loading

I've got an Angular application which has lots of feature modules which are lazy loaded for the sake of speed.

The problem is that different users have different rights, thus one user may have no rights open some modules, therefore I would like to prevent them to load this module.

As it turns out I cannot set `canLoad` and `preloadStrategy: PreloadAllModules` at the same time. Is there a possibility to

1. Check if the user have right to load modules
2. **preload** those which they can

I know that there is a `canActivate` but I also want to lighten my application, because if user cannot see this module they don't have to load it, but they would like to preload others which they can access to open them faster.

Comment: Maybe custom preload strategy?

Comment: Could you point me to this?

Comment: Google - tons of hits. https://coryrylan.com/blog/custom-preloading-and-lazy-loading-strategies-with-angular

Comment: use custom-preloading-strategy https://angular.io/guide/router#custom-preloading-strategy